# Windows Server 2019 high round-trip time low transfer bandwidth

Tags: windows, networking, backup, windows-server-2019, iperf

I have two Windows Servers 2019 with a round-trip time of 88 ms between them. When I try to measure bandwidth with iperf3 I get only around 16 Mbits/sec in both directions with a single stream. To get the actual bandwidth assigned of 1 Gbits/s I need to increase windows size to 1M and run it in 10 parallel streams using -w 1M -P 10. I also get good performance when I copy files between them.

Is there anything I can do to increase single stream performance? Here is the thing: Windows Server Backup is limited by this number. It takes some 2-4 hours for a simple backup to complete (copying the file of same size takes 15 minutes).

Here are the settings on both servers:

netsh int tcp show global

```
TCP Global Parameters
----------------------------------------------
Receive-Side Scaling State          : enabled
Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level    : normal
Add-On Congestion Control Provider  : default
ECN Capability                      : enabled
RFC 1323 Timestamps                 : disabled
Initial RTO                         : 3000
Receive Segment Coalescing State    : enabled
Non Sack Rtt Resiliency             : disabled
Max SYN Retransmissions             : 2
Fast Open                           : disabled
Fast Open Fallback                  : enabled
HyStart                             : enabled
Pacing Profile                      : off
```

Get-NetTCPSetting -SettingName Internet

```
SettingName                     : Internet
MinRto(ms)                      : 300
InitialCongestionWindow(MSS)    : 10
CongestionProvider              : CUBIC
CwndRestart                     : False
DelayedAckTimeout(ms)           : 40
DelayedAckFrequency             : 2
MemoryPressureProtection        : Enabled
AutoTuningLevelLocal            : Normal
AutoTuningLevelGroupPolicy      : NotConfigured
AutoTuningLevelEffective        : Local
EcnCapability                   : Enabled
Timestamps                      : Disabled
InitialRto(ms)                  : 3000
ScalingHeuristics               : Disabled
DynamicPortRangeStartPort       : 49152
DynamicPortRangeNumberOfPorts   : 16384
AutomaticUseCustom              : Disabled
NonSackRttResiliency            : Disabled
ForceWS                         : Enabled
MaxSynRetransmissions           : 2
AutoReusePortRangeStartPort     : 0
AutoReusePortRangeNumberOfPorts : 0
```

Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name External | Format-Table -Autosize

```
Name     DisplayName                       DisplayValue                   RegistryKeyword                     RegistryValue
----     -----------                       ------------                   ---------------                     -------------
External Encapsulation Overhead            0                              *EncapOverhead                      {0}
External Encapsulated Task Offload         Enabled                        *EncapsulatedPacketTaskOffload      {1}
External NVGRE Encapsulated Task Offload   Enabled                        *EncapsulatedPacketTaskOffloadNvgre {1}
External VXLAN Encapsulated Task Offload   Enabled                        *EncapsulatedPacketTaskOffloadVxlan {1}
External Flow Control                      Rx & Tx Enabled                *FlowControl                        {3}
External Header Data Split                 Disabled                       *HeaderDataSplit                    {0}
External Interrupt Moderation              Enabled                        *InterruptModeration                {1}
External IPv4 Checksum Offload             Rx & Tx Enabled                *IPChecksumOffloadIPv4              {3}
External Jumbo Packet                      Disabled                       *JumboPacket                        {1514}
External Large Send Offload V2 (IPv4)      Enabled                        *LsoV2IPv4                          {1}
External Large Send Offload V2 (IPv6)      Enabled                        *LsoV2IPv6                          {1}
External Maximum Number of RSS Processors  16                             *MaxRssProcessors                   {16}
External Preferred NUMA node               65535                          *NumaNodeId                         {65535}
External Maximum Number of RSS Queues      2 Queues                       *NumRssQueues                       {2}
External Packet Priority & VLAN            Packet Priority & VLAN Enabled *PriorityVLANTag                    {3}
External Receive Buffers                   512                            *ReceiveBuffers                     {512}
External Recv Segment Coalescing (IPv4)    Enabled                        *RSCIPv4                            {1}
External Recv Segment Coalescing (IPv6)    Enabled                        *RSCIPv6                            {1}
External Receive Side Scaling              Enabled                        *RSS                                {1}
External Starting RSS CPU                  0                              *RssBaseProcNumber                  {0}
External Virtual Switch RSS                Enabled                        *RssOnHostVPorts                    {1}
External RSS load balancing profile        ClosestProcessor               *RSSProfile                         {1}
External Speed & Duplex                    Auto Negotiation               *SpeedDuplex                        {0}
External SR-IOV                            Enabled                        *SRIOV                              {1}
External TCP Checksum Offload (IPv4)       Rx & Tx Enabled                *TCPChecksumOffloadIPv4             {3}
External TCP Checksum Offload (IPv6)       Rx & Tx Enabled                *TCPChecksumOffloadIPv6             {3}
External Transmit Buffers                  512                            *TransmitBuffers                    {512}
External UDP Checksum Offload (IPv4)       Rx & Tx Enabled                *UDPChecksumOffloadIPv4             {3}
External UDP Checksum Offload (IPv6)       Rx & Tx Enabled                *UDPChecksumOffloadIPv6             {3}
External Virtual Machine Queues            Enabled                        *VMQ                                {1}
External VXLAN UDP Destination Port Number 4789                           *VxlanUDPPortNumber                 {4789}
External Wake on Magic Packet              Enabled                        *WakeOnMagicPacket                  {1}
External Wake on Pattern Match             Enabled                        *WakeOnPattern                      {1}
External DMA Coalescing                    Disabled                       DMACoalescing                       {0}
External Enable PME                        Disabled                       EnablePME                           {0}
External Interrupt Moderation Rate         Adaptive                       ITR                                 {65535}
External Log Link State Event              Enabled                        LogLinkStateEvent                   {51}
External Locally Administered Address                                     NetworkAddress                      {--}
External VLAN ID                           0                              VlanId                              {0}
External Wake on Link Settings             Disabled                       WakeOnLink                          {0}
```

iperf3 -c address

```
Connecting to host address, port 5201
[  4] local address port 57162 connected to address port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   768 KBytes  6.28 Mbits/sec
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  2.00 MBytes  16.8 Mbits/sec
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  2.12 MBytes  17.8 Mbits/sec
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  2.00 MBytes  16.8 Mbits/sec
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  2.00 MBytes  16.8 Mbits/sec
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  2.00 MBytes  16.8 Mbits/sec
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  2.00 MBytes  16.8 Mbits/sec
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  2.12 MBytes  17.8 Mbits/sec
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  2.00 MBytes  16.8 Mbits/sec
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  2.12 MBytes  17.9 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  19.1 MBytes  16.0 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  19.1 MBytes  16.0 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

iperf3 -c address -w 1M -P 10 | Select-String 'SUM'

```
[SUM]   0.00-1.00   sec  16.1 MBytes   135 Mbits/sec
[SUM]   1.00-2.00   sec  44.1 MBytes   371 Mbits/sec
[SUM]   2.00-3.00   sec   105 MBytes   879 Mbits/sec
[SUM]   3.00-4.00   sec   109 MBytes   913 Mbits/sec
[SUM]   4.00-5.00   sec   110 MBytes   922 Mbits/sec
[SUM]   5.00-6.00   sec  93.1 MBytes   781 Mbits/sec
[SUM]   6.00-7.00   sec  96.0 MBytes   805 Mbits/sec
[SUM]   7.00-8.00   sec  98.2 MBytes   824 Mbits/sec
[SUM]   8.00-9.00   sec   101 MBytes   847 Mbits/sec
[SUM]   9.00-10.00  sec   102 MBytes   858 Mbits/sec
[SUM]   0.00-10.00  sec   874 MBytes   733 Mbits/sec                  sender
[SUM]   0.00-10.00  sec   874 MBytes   733 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `iperf3`? Especially regarding the window size.

Comment: I've added the output of iperf3 to my question.